# control Apache redirects with ht-access

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have three directories inside my public_html in cpanel host...

#### site & blog & tests

i need to redirect all requests like this:

- requests that starts with (blog) to /blog/???
- requests that starts with (tests) to /tests/???
- any other request will be redirected to the /site/??? directory

notice i need the rest of the uri to remain intact after the requets EX:

 request `product/cate1/15` will be redirected to the `site/product/cate1/15`

#### how to do this using php & htacess file ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(site|blog|tests) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: thanks, works perfectly...<br>
but i noticed an unexpected behavior:<br>
when i type one of them like (domain+/tests/) works fine but when i type (domain+/tests) with out the final / it come out with this message: <br>
---> This webpage has a redirect loop <br>
is there any solution for this problem ???

Comment: works perfectly... thanks very much... 
do you know any good tutorial to learn .htaccess ?
where did you learn how to use it ?